# Do we want Hats?

Tags: discussion

Since Genealogy.SE doesn't have any mods yet, I'm posting to you all directly.

### What are these hats you speak of?

Last year around Christmas time [arQAde](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) had an awesome promotion in which they awarded hats for gravatars for completing basic tasks around the site. If you don't remember it, here is a [link](http://stackexchange.com/promos/2/hat-dash) the promo from last year (and [another!](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/)).

[image: hats]

[image: hatrack]

This year, SE is planning to run it for *everyone* because we all love hats, right? *Right?!*

### Why are you making a meta post?

In order to get this awesome hat promotion, we have to ***opt in***. That means acting on this meta post: voting it up, answering in the affirmative, positive comments, and/or just directing positive energy this direction!

HOWEVER: this promotion is **optional** for sites, and/or individual users. If you all *do not* want this event to happen here, feel free to voice that opinion. Users who with to opt out will be provided with an "I hate Hats" link to remove the presence of hats from their view of the site.

I think this is a great opportunity for Genealogy.SE to grow and get even more awesome content as we head towards gradumatation. Plus, it'll be a lot of fun!

### What if I want to know more?

Please let us know what you think -- this is *your* site and we want to do things that *you* feel support the community here!

I'm happy to answer any questions in comments/answers. I'll do my best to be as forthcoming as I can without giving away too much!

Comment: This was adapted from [this post elsewhere on the network](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/do-you-like-hats).

Comment: Are hats temporary?

Comment: @Luke Yes! Hats will persist for the duration of the event, then disappear. Users will see their "hat rack" for some time on a landing/external promo page for a while, but then that will also disappear. :)

Answer (score 7):

[Y](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/72/Hardee_Hat.jpg)[e](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/PithHelmetTruman.jpg)[s](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/MuseeMarine-ShakoMarine.jpg)[,](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Tophat.jpg) [l](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fe/PanamaHatHarryTruman.jpg)[e](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/K%C3%A9pi_gendarmerie_pontificale.jpg)[t](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/Hatt.jpg)['](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/YellowHardHat.jpg)[s](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/02/MetHelmet.png) [h](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/PilgrimsHat.jpg)[a](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Texas_Tech_Red_Raiders_baseball_cap.jpg)[v](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Beaver-felt-hat-ftl.jpg)[e](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/1800s_-Masonic_Knights_Templar-_Beaver_Fur_Chapeaux_Hat.jpg) [h](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Chapeaux_en_peau_de_castor.jpg)[a](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/1st_Sardinia_Grenadiers_Bastille_Day_2007_n1.jpg)[t](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0d/StrawBoater.jpg)[s](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/Charlie_Chaplin.jpg)[!](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7f/Beret_SG.jpg) [I](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/Bicorne_officier_g%C3%A9nie_IMG_3207.jpg)[t](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Tigerstripehat.JPG)['](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/CampaignHat.svg)[s](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Caubeen.png) [j](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/Coonskin_cap.JPG)[u](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/Dunce_cap_from_LOC_3c04163u.png)[s](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Luftwaffen_Schiffchen.jpg)[t](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/Schutzhelm.jpg) [a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aMortarboards.JPG) [b](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/M1951_Ridgeway_Field_Cap.gif)[i](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Porkpie.jpg)[t](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Australian_Army_ceremonial_slouch_hat.png) [o](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Harry_S_Truman_sombrero.jpg)[f](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Felthat.jpg) [f](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Chef_wiki.png)[u](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bb/Trilbyhat.JPG)[n](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Truckerhat.jpg)[.](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Grayushanka.jpg) [I](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9b/Robert_W._Patten_%28The_Umbrella_Man%29.png)[f](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ef/Hugo_Salmson_turban.jpg) [s](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Tyrolean_hat_3.jpg)[o](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/92/Barret-tou-ala-ampla.JPG)[m](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Nonno_cappello.png)[e](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Science_ofDress216Fig19.png)[b](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Science_ofDress216Fig20.png)[o](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/90/Yellow_Filzhut.png)[d](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Sombrero_de_Freud.jpg)[y](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Mooskappe.JPG) [d](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/70-161-AB_Fore_and_Aft_Hat,_CDR_Albert._S._Greene_%285716605132%29.jpg)[o](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Centre_de_Documentaci%C3%B3_Museu_T%C3%A8xtil_de_Terrassa-_Barret_Raimon_Casellas.JPG)[e](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Tudor_Bonnet.jpg)[s](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Sailor_hat_%28PSF%29.png)[n](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Brigadier_ohne_Kommando.jpg)['](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Chambers_1908_Tarboosh.png)[t](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Hatt2.png) [l](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/Hat_worn_by_Congressman_Ford.JPG)[i](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Str%C3%B6hl-Rangkronen-Fig._44.png)[k](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Kubanka.jpg)[e](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Boonie_wuestentarn.jpg) [i](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/NMAH_DC_-_IMG_8756.JPG)[t](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/78/Meloun.jpg)[,](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/Pillboxhat.jpg) [t](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b8/Finnish_doctoral_hat.JPG)[h](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/SteinacherM%C3%BCtzeAlt.jpg)[e](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/93/Royal_Australian_Regiment_Vietnam_War_bush_hat.JPG)[y](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Campaign_hat,_Company_K,_First_North_Carolina_Volunteers,_1898-1899_-_North_Carolina_Museum_of_History_-_DSC06020.JPG) [c](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/da/BischofBowle.png)[a](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Borsalino_panama.jpg)[n](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/Collapsible_top_hat_IMGP9647.jpg) [j](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/2011-148-91_Uniform,_Officer,_Garrison_cap,_Grey_%286012215644%29.jpg)[u](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Snapback_Hat.jpg)[s](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Au_service_des_Tsars_-_Shako_%D0%ADPT-10900_et_%D0%ADPT_10804_001.jpg)[t](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Bon%C3%A9_da_farda_de_gala_1.JPG) [h](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Grey_Pork_Pie.jpg)[i](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aTophat2.jpg)[t](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Peter_III%27s_tricorne_01_by_shakko.jpg) <kbd>I  hate hats</kbd>.

Comment: This is amazing.

Comment: Yes! Nice, Luke.

Comment: Hats... I'm in.

Comment: Wow.​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Did you make an account just to say those three letters (how did you evade the minimum length)?

Comment: Luke, how'd you get a hat?

Comment: Photoshop......

Comment: @JustinY [Here you go](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VFjkx.png)