# Do you want hats?

Tags: discussion

Yes, [it's that time of year again](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1314/56). Half the world bundles up with cocoa and candy canes for the season and the other half surfs the waves with Santa. Meanwhile, here at Genealogy.SE, we have the option to celebrate with a unique, age-old Stack Exchange tradition (of two years): **[hats](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/)**!

[image]

Users earn hats (new and redesigned for 2013!) for their gravatars to wear that will last the holiday season (Dec. 16, 2013 - Jan. 3, 2014).

<sub>If you hate hats (*gasp*), you can simply click the <kbd>I hate hats</kbd> button and all hats will disappear to you.</sub>

However, in order for Genealogy.SE to opt in and join the fun, **we need to hear your opinion**. Do you want to participate in the Winter Bash here at Genealogy.SE? Leave your thoughts below and a few cookies and milk for the mods!

Comment: Let’s give it a try!

Comment: That's the spirit! :D

Comment: I like my current “hat” (it’s a wig) so much, I’d like to keep it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I loves hats, I does. Milk and cookies are cool too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please! Hat!  Cookies!  Milk! It's all good (except the milk and crumbs shouldn't get into the keyboard).

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't sure, but now yes! I'm  enjoying the hats. I also like the unicorns we had a few years ago. It's all good fun.
.

Answer (score 0):

I hates hats, I does.
Not wild about milk and cookies either.

Comment: Don't worry, the hats are new and redesigned. So, no head lice from last year. :P