# Do you want hats? 2014 Winter Bash

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Yes, [it's that time of year again](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1778/56). Half the world bundles up with cocoa and candy canes for the season and the other half surfs the waves with Santa. Meanwhile, here at Genealogy.SE, we have the option to celebrate with a unique, age-old Stack Exchange tradition (of three years): **[hats](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/)**!

[image]

Users earn hats (new and redesigned for 2014!) for their gravatars to wear that will last the holiday season (15 December 2014 - 4 January 2015).

If you hate hats (*gasp*), you can simply click the <kbd>I hate hats</kbd> button and make all the hats invisible to you.

However, **we want to hear your opinion**.  This year (unlike previous years) we have to send in a Grinch form in order to NOT have hats -- otherwise, we'll have them.  Let us know by 30 November 2014, or be prepared to press that <kbd>I hate hats</kbd> button.

At the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

Do you want to participate in the Winter Bash here at Genealogy.SE? Leave your thoughts below and a few cookies and milk for the mods!

Comment: Jan needs a hat for her cat.

Comment: I don't think it will be as easy for me to get hats as it was last year.  So everyone else needs to step up their game so I can see all the hats!

Comment: The advice Jan and I had from SE was "All responses will need to be in by 1 December 2014. Sites that haven’t responded by then will be considered to have opted in to the event." so, with the vote the way it was, it looks like we'll have hats from 15 December 2014 to 4 January 2015.

Answer (score 5):

Vote for this answer if you would like G&FH SE to have hats available for those who would like to see their avatars adorned with them during the festive season.

Comment: +1 Hats are fun. Hats are great. Some are funny. Some are cute. They motivate you to do more ... to get more hats ...or to get the one you want. Or if you're really good, you can get a secret hat. For status, wear one no one else got. What more could you want that a hat-attack?  (p.s. Unicorns are fun, too).

Answer (score 3):

Here's [our Genealogy & Family History SE Winter Bash 2014 leaderboard](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/genealogy.stackexchange.com), for who's earned the most hats on our site.

Comment: Congrats to @PearsonArtPhoto for getting 10 hats!

Answer (score 2):

It's December 21st, so I do a little survey of the top users list for the month at Genealogy SE.

6 of the top 12 users for the month are wearing hats.

That's a little below the 10 of the top 12 users at Stackoverflow. But that is to be expected, because we programmers are more geeky.

I've worn 4 different hats already.  :-)

Comment: Oh, you got Fascinating!

Comment: @JanMurphy - Yes, but I just can't bring myself to wear it. Spock is even too geeky for me.

Comment: Up to six hats now. Just got a Chameleon. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I loathe hats with a passion .

PS: Be fair -- vote for one answer or the other.

Comment: Edited to fix a typo. I don't plan to go around editing posts here for one-letter typos, but my personal rule is to nit-pick when a typo accidentally produces a different word.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question, to see some of the best hat/avatar combinations people have put together:

[Whats the best use of hats that you've seen?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280924/whats-the-best-use-of-hat-that-youve-seen/280928#280928)

---

Less than 12 hours later:  Unbelievable, but that question, which was in Meta where I thought opinions are supposed to be expressed, got put on hold and then deleted for the reason that it was "primarily opinion-based".

If Stack Exchange can put up a fun event like the Winter Bash, why on earth won't the members of Stack Exchange let us enjoy it?

Please vote to undelete and then reopen that question.