# Do we want hats? Announcing the 2015 Winter Bash!

Tags: discussion

Yes, it's that time of year again! Half the world bundles up with cocoa and candy canes for the season and the other half surfs the waves with Santa. Meanwhile, here at Genealogy.SE, we have the option to celebrate with a unique, age-old Stack Exchange tradition (of four years): hats!

By completing certain tasks, Stack Exchange users earn virtual hats (new and redesigned for 2015!) for their gravatars to wear that will last the holiday season (14 December 2015 - 3 January 2016). We will be able to see all the hats we've earned on http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com. Here's a screen shot from last year's leaderboard:

[image]

Check that page for the FAQ after Winter Bash starts for an explanation of how things work -- right now it's a countdown.

This year the default is that everyone gets hats unless we mods send in a Grinch form in order to NOT have hats.  If you hate hats (*gasp*), you can simply click the <kbd>I hate hats</kbd> button and make all the hats invisible to you.

But no matter whether you like hats or hate them, **we still want to hear your opinion.** Let us know by 9 December 2015, or be prepared to press that <kbd>I hate hats</kbd> button.

At the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

Do you want to participate in the Winter Bash here at Genealogy.SE? Leave your thoughts below and a few cookies and milk for the mods!

---

For previous years see:

- [Do we want Hats?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1314/1006) (2012)
- [Do you want hats?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1778/1006) (2013)
- [Do you want hats? 2014 Winter Bash](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1929/1006)

Answer (score 4):

I love hats! Hooray for Winter Bash!

Answer (score 4):

I rather like this one -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If we can't have unicorns, then hats are the next best thing.

Answer (score 0):

Bah humbug to hats. (You were expecting that, right?)

Comment: Let us know if you don't see the button.