# Do we want hats? Announcing the 2016 Winter Bash!

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Yes, it's that time of year again! Here at Genealogy.SE, we have the option to celebrate this time of the year with a unique, age-old Stack Exchange tradition: hats!

By completing certain tasks, Stack Exchange users earn virtual hats (new and redesigned for 2016!) for their gravatars to wear that will last the holiday season (19 December 2016 - 8 January 2017). We will be able to see all the hats we've earned on http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com. Here's a screen shot from last year's leaderboard:

[image]

Check that page for the FAQ after Winter Bash starts for an explanation of how things work -- right now it's a countdown.

This year the default is that everyone gets hats unless we mods send in a Grinch form in order to NOT have hats.  If you hate hats (*gasp*), you can simply click the <kbd>I hate hats</kbd> button and make all the hats invisible to you.

But no matter whether you like hats or hate them, **we still want to hear your opinion.** Let us know by 12 December 2016, or be prepared to press that <kbd>I hate hats</kbd> button.

At the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

Do you want to participate in the Winter Bash here at Genealogy.SE? Leave your thoughts below and a few cookies and milk for the mods!

---

For previous years see:

- [Do we want Hats?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1314/1006) (2012)
- [Do you want hats?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1778/1006) (2013)
- [Do you want hats? 2014 Winter Bash](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1929/1006)
- [Do we want hats? Announcing the 2015 Winter Bash!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2105/1006)

---

As of 7:04 PM Pacific on 31 Dec 2016,

> 45 users from this site have earned a total of 115 hats!

---

Here's [the results to this year's Winter Bash](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/say-farewell-to-winter-bash-2016/)

Comment: Winter Bash 2016 started today with G&FH participating!

Answer (score 4):

Hats!
I rarely wear hats IRL - they make me look "weird", or "sort of like a murderer", at least according to my wife.
But virtual hats? Bring 'em on!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes! Yes! Yes!  I love hats!!  Bring 'em on!

Hopefully one year, they'll bring the Unicorns back.

Answer (score 1):

It will come as no surprise that I still hate hats!

Comment: Boo. Bad bad bad.

Comment: Just doing my duty. :(

Comment: @lkessler Each to their own.  I recognise hats are inevitable -- doesn't mean I can't have my say.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl - I know. I'm just having fun with this.